# How to set default time zone for SQL Warehouse in Databricks?

Tags: timezone, azure-databricks, sql-data-warehouse

I want to change the default time zone for SQL Warehoue in the SQL Persona, in Databricks.

When I try to Edit the SQL warehouse settings in the "SQL Warehouses" section, I am not able to find any setting where I can set the time zone.

I am aware that I can set the time zone by running the query "SET TIME ZONE 'GMT+10';" in the query editor. But, I need to run this command every time I start the SQL warehouse.

I don't want to repeat the above command every time I run a query in the query editor. Instead, I want to set the local time zone as the default time zone of the SQL warehouse.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The system default is `UTC.

The TIMEZONE configuration parameter controls the local timezone used for timestamp operations within a session.

You can set this parameter at the session level using the [SET statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-conf-mgmt-set) and at the global level using [SQL configuration parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/admin/sql-configuration-parameters) or the [SQL Warehouse API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/warehouses/setworkspacewarehouseconfig).

An alternative way to set the session timezone is using the [SET TIME ZONE statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-conf-mgmt-set-timezone).